# Are $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ abstractly isomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

The groups $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ are usually "the" classic example of nonisomorphic Lie groups whose corresponding Lie algebras are isomorphic. While I understand the isomorphism of their algebras, it was not obvious at all to me that we must have $SU(2) \not\cong SO(3)$, I think one can conclude that by looking at the topological structure, for example the fact that their fundamental groups are nonisomorphic should suffice (I *think*).

What if we forget about the topology and consider them just as abstract groups? I've been trying to find some obstruction but all the facts I know about them, for example $SO(3) \cong SU(2)/Z(SU(2))$, don't seem to be enough! Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Comparing their centers should work, I think.

Comment: @Thorgott Oh! I thought both centers were isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2$ but actually I'm not quite sure about $Z(SO(3))$ now, I'll try to work out the details tomorrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to distinguish these two is that $\pi_1(\operatorname{SU}(2))=0$ while $\pi_1(\operatorname{SO}(3))=\Bbb{Z}/2$. Actually, more is true. You can realize $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ as the unit quaternions (hence diffeomorphic to $S^3$), and $\operatorname{SO}(3)=\operatorname{SU}(2)/Z(\operatorname{SU}(2))$ realizes $\operatorname{SU}(2)\to\operatorname{SO}(3)$ as a $2-$fold covering map. From what we know about the topology of $S^3$ we get indeed that $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ is simply connected and hence that $\pi_1(\operatorname{SO}(3))\cong \Bbb{Z}/2.$

Clearly, I misread part of the question. Sorry – we can analyze the centres of these groups to find that $Z(\operatorname{SO}(3))=\{I_3\}$, while $Z(\operatorname{SU}(2))=\{\pm I_2\}$. This is a good exercise to do for yourself. The fact about $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ follows from thinking about the identification as quaternions, while the fact for $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ can be understood by thinking about $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ acting on $S^2$. You want to show that the centres are of the form $\{\text{Scalar matrices}\}\cap G$.

I think there is also a nice proof of this using Schur's Lemma.

Comment: This distinguishes them topologically, but does it prove they are not isomorphic as (just) groups?

Comment: Whoops. I guess I missed part of the question. Anyway, the centres will do the trick.

Comment: I did find the centers of $SU(n)$ as an exercise a while ago but I was somehow convinced that $SO(3)$ had nontrivial center too! Thanks for the thorough answer